# asp.net vs asp.net core - object passed as reference does not get updated in core

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-2.2

I use a service/repository patternand validation as described in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs). Services have a ValidationDictionary property.

```
   public interface IValidationDictionary
    {
        void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);
        bool IsValid { get; }
    }
```

Services get injected into the ctor of the controllers. In the body of the constructor the validationdictioary property is set. I use a wrapper class to wrap around the modelstate of the controller.

```
 public AuthenticationController(
        IOptionsMonitor<PasswordOptions> optionsAccessor,
        AppUserService appUserService,
        ILogger<AuthenticationController> logger, IConfiguration config) : base(logger, config)
    {
        _passwordOptions = optionsAccessor.CurrentValue;
        _appUserService = appUserService;
        _appUserService.ValidationDictionary = new ModelStateWrapper(ModelState);
    }

   public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
    {
        private readonly ModelStateDictionary _modelState;

        public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelstate)
        {
            _modelState = modelstate;
        }

        public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
        {
            _modelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
        }

        public bool IsValid => _modelState.IsValid;
    }
```

In the service, when validation goes wrong I add an error to the validation dictionary.

```
ValidationDictionary.AddError("", ErrorMessages.PasswordIsRequired);
```

When the validationdictionary contains any errors a DataValidationException is throw.

```
    if (!ValidationDictionary.IsValid)
    {
        throw new DataValidationException();
    }
```

That exception is captured in the controller to update the view with the extra errors in the modelstate.

This approach worked fine in asp.net but in asp.net core it is not working anymore.

When I check the validationdictionary in the service it contains all expected errors. Once back in the controller after catching the exception the ModelState is in it is original state = state before moving to the service.

When I move the assignment of the modelstate to the validationdictionary from the constructor to the top of an action. It is working fine.

```
      public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterVM VM)
        {
            try
            {
                _appUserService.ValidationDictionary = new ModelStateWrapper(ModelState);
....
```

This is very error prone, so absolutely not desirable.

As a workaround I added a property for the service with only a getter.

```
  protected AppUserService AppUserService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_appUserService.ValidationDictionary == null)
            {
                _appUserService.ValidationDictionary = new ModelStateWrapper(ModelState);
            }
            return _appUserService;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions for a better solution ?

Comment: Is the modelstate recreated at the moment an action is fired / triggered ?

Comment: You are not passing it by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Modelstate is created at the moment a controller is created, but again one is created when a method is called. Hence referencing the modelstate created at control creation time, is actually referencing a modelstate that will not be updated when calling a method.

The sollution is only referencing the modelstate at moment when you call the method. Hence the mentioned workaround is the actual final solution.